# Direct3d vertex buffer usage type, performance and c++amp?

Tags: winapi, graphics, direct3d, direct3d11, c++-amp

I'm new to direct3d and graphics programming in general, the program I'm writing changes vertices once per frame after applying non trivial computation per frame, according to this [Direct3d programming tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Using_Dynamic_Vertex_and_Index_Buffers)

I should use dynamic buffers for such task, but it says that it's performance is expectable, searching the web I found [Fastest way to update vertex buffer](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/612041-fastest-way-to-update-vertex-buffers-directx-sharpdx/)

Scroll down to Xoofx answer(Designer of Sharpdx) according to him updating a subresource is better than using dynamic buffers and as far as I know updating a subresource is used only with default buffers.

Which usage should I go with and what is (staging) ?

If I decide to use C++ AMP to do the computation (I understand that it uses the gpu as a processor) is there any way to set the buffer usage to default and still access it through the cpu using C++ AMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program can create a C++ AMP array associated with an existing Direct3D buffer using the `make_array()` function.

```
template<typename T, int N>
array<T,N> make_array(const extent& ext, IUnknown* buffer);
```

The Direct3D buffer must implement the `ID3D11Buffer` interface. It must support raw views  (`D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_ALLOW_RAW_VIEWS`) and allow `SHADER_RESOURCE` and 
`UNORDERED_ACCESS` binding. The buffer itself must be of the correct size, the size of the extent 
multiplied by the size of the buffer type.

The `get_buffer()` function supports the reverse operation, getting a Direct3D buffer interface from 
an array. As when getting a device, the returned `IUnknown` must be queried for the desired interface.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
array<int, 1> arr(1024);
CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> buffer;
IUnknown* unkBuf = get_buffer(arr);
hr = unkBuf->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Buffer), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&buffer));
```